# How to "re-install" a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Question is pretty simple so instead of writting two commands is there one substitute?
e.g.

```
gem uninstall subexec

gem install subexec
```

Is there just re-install, or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the following restores the gem to the contents of the `.gem` file:

```
gem pristine <gem name here>
```

You can also run that with `--all` if you want to clean your entire set of installed gems.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such command. You can, however, fit them on one line, if that's what you seek.

```
gem uninstall subexec && gem install subexec
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you have to do an uninstall and install.

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/book/2

Answer (score 0):

If you use bundler for gem installations then all you need to do is edit the gemfile and then run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem update <gem-name>
```

would update to latest available version.
or

```
gem update
```

would update all gems to latest versions.